# NSManagedObject nil value

Tags: nsmanagedobject

I save data with CoreData. I have an Array and the last occurrence is 'nil' value. I do not want to save the 'nil' value in CoreData. **I try to check the 'nil' value but I can not achieve**. My code:

```
for (NSManagedObject *category in array) 
{ 
        //if (![category isEqual:nil]) {     <- FAILED ATTEMPT
        //if (![category isFault]) {           <- FAILED ATTEMPT
        //if (category != NULL) {           <- FAILED ATTEMPT

         [ more Objective-C code ...]

         // Insert Objects in the Core Data
         theLine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entName
                                                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //}
  }
```

I can not understand why is so hard to check a NSManagedObject 'nil value'.

In my code, **'category'** is a NSManagedObject. I want to know when it has 'nil' value:

- (NSManagedObject)  **isEqual**
- (NSManagedObject)  **isFault**
- (NSManagedObject)  **= NULL**

Any of these options does not run. Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just use `if(category)` or `if(category == nil)` they should check if it is equal to nil.

Failing this you could do a for loop like:

```
for (int cycle =0 ; cycle < [array count]; cycle++){
   if ([[array objectAtIndex:cycle]isKindOfClass[NSNull class]]){


////Do some code here

   }

}
```

This will check is the value of the object is not Null because your loop will only look at NSManagedObjects